# Image stitching with opencvsharp

Tags: c#, opencv, opencv-stitching

I want to make image stitching with openCvSharp but something goes wrong. Since I do not get the right output of 2 image stitched together.

I was fallowing the tutorial in python [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11Md7HWh2ZV6_g3iCYSUw76VNr4HzxcX5#scrollTo=ww8t8MhAE9gY) and converting it in to C# code.

Here are 2 photo examples

[image]
[image]

The output where image should be stitched I get wrong result. It looks the same as image 2.
[image]

I gues something goes wrong in line, or somewhere after the line

```
        Cv2.WarpPerspective(trainImg, result, H, new OpenCvSharp.Size(width, height));
```

Here is the full code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool debugImages = true;
        string locationFolder = "";
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.CheckFileExists = true;
        dlg.Multiselect = true;

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            locationFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(dlg.FileNames[0]) + "\\output\\";

            List<Mat> imagesMat = new List<Mat>();
            for (var i = 0; i < dlg.FileNames.Length; i++)
            {
                using (Bitmap fromFile = new Bitmap(dlg.FileNames[i]))
                {
                    Mat source = BitmapConverter.ToMat(fromFile);
                    imagesMat.Add(source);
                }
            }
            if (imagesMat.Count != 2)
                throw new Exception("Select only 2 images!!!");

            int imageCounter = 0;
            Mat trainImg = imagesMat[0];
            Mat queryImg = imagesMat[1];

            Mat trainImg_gray = new Mat();
            Mat queryImg_gray = new Mat();
            Cv2.CvtColor(trainImg, trainImg_gray, ColorConversionCodes.BGRA2GRAY);
            Cv2.CvtColor(queryImg, queryImg_gray, ColorConversionCodes.BGRA2GRAY);

            // detecting keypoints
            // FastFeatureDetector, StarDetector, SIFT, SURF, ORB, BRISK, MSER, GFTTDetector, DenseFeatureDetector, SimpleBlobDetector
            string method = "SURF";
            string feature_matching = "bf"; //bf, knn
            var descriptor = SURF.Create(500, 4, 2, true);

            Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
            Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();
            KeyPoint[] kpsA;
            KeyPoint[] kpsB;
            descriptor.DetectAndCompute(trainImg_gray, null, out kpsA, descriptors1);
            descriptor.DetectAndCompute(queryImg_gray, null, out kpsB, descriptors2);

            // Match descriptor vectors 
            //var flannMatcher = new FlannBasedMatcher();
            DMatch[] matches;
            if (feature_matching == "bf")
                matches = matchKeyPointsBF(descriptors1, descriptors2, method);
            else
                matches = matchKeyPointsKNN(descriptors1, descriptors2, 0.75, method);

            var bfView = new Mat();
            Cv2.DrawMatches(trainImg, kpsA, queryImg, kpsB, matches, bfView, null, flags: DrawMatchesFlags.NotDrawSinglePoints);
            if (debugImages)
            {
                using (Bitmap resultBitmap = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(bfView))
                    resultBitmap.Save(locationFolder + (imageCounter++).ToString().PadLeft(3, '0') + ".png", ImageFormat.Png); //1
            }

            Mat H = getHomography(kpsA, kpsB, descriptors1, descriptors2, matches, 4);
            if (H == null)
                throw new Exception("No Homography!!!");
            //for (var i = 0; i < H.Cols; i++)
            //{
            //    for (var j = 0; j < H.Rows; j++)
            //        Console.Write(H.At<float>(i, j) + " ");
            //    Console.WriteLine("");
            //}

            double width = trainImg.Size().Width + queryImg.Size().Width;
            double height = trainImg.Size().Height + queryImg.Size().Height;

            Mat result = new Mat();
            Cv2.WarpPerspective(trainImg, result, H, new OpenCvSharp.Size(width, height));
            if (debugImages)
            {
                using (Bitmap resultBitmap = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(result))
                    resultBitmap.Save(locationFolder + (imageCounter++).ToString().PadLeft(3, '0') + ".png", ImageFormat.Png); //1
            }
            result[new Rect(new OpenCvSharp.Point(0, 0), new OpenCvSharp.Size(queryImg.Size().Width, queryImg.Size().Height))] = queryImg;
            if (debugImages)
            {
                using (Bitmap resultBitmap = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(result))
                    resultBitmap.Save(locationFolder + (imageCounter++).ToString().PadLeft(3, '0') + ".png", ImageFormat.Png); //2
            }

            //# transform the panorama image to grayscale and threshold it 
            Mat gray = result.Clone();
            Cv2.CvtColor(result, gray, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
            Mat thresh = new Mat();
            double thresh2 = Cv2.Threshold(gray, thresh, 0, 255, ThresholdTypes.Binary);
            //# Finds contours from the binary image
            OpenCvSharp.Point[][] cnts;
            HierarchyIndex[] hierarchy;
            Cv2.FindContours(thresh, out cnts, out hierarchy, RetrievalModes.External, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxSimple);
            OpenCvSharp.Point[] cnts2 = new OpenCvSharp.Point[cnts[0].Length];
            for (var k = 0; k < cnts[0].Length; k++)
                cnts2[k] = cnts[0][k];
            //InputArray ptsA = InputArray.Create(cnts2);
            //var c = Cv2.ContourArea(ptsA, true);
            OpenCvSharp.Rect xywh = Cv2.BoundingRect(cnts2);
            result = result[new Rect(new OpenCvSharp.Point(xywh.X, xywh.Y), new OpenCvSharp.Size(xywh.Width, xywh.Height))];
            //result = result[new Rect(new OpenCvSharp.Point(0, 0), new OpenCvSharp.Size(256, 256))];
            Bitmap endResultBitmap = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(result);
            endResultBitmap.Save(locationFolder + (imageCounter++).ToString().PadLeft(3, '0') + ".png", ImageFormat.Png); //4


            Environment.Exit(-1);
        }
    }

    private BFMatcher createMatcher(string method, bool crossCheck)
    {
        //"Create and return a Matcher Object"
        if (method == "SURF" || method == "SIFT")
            return new BFMatcher(NormTypes.L2, crossCheck);
        else //if (method == "ORB" || method == "BRISK")
            return new BFMatcher(NormTypes.Hamming, crossCheck);
    }

    private DMatch[] matchKeyPointsBF(Mat featuresA, Mat featuresB, string method)
    {
        BFMatcher bf = createMatcher(method, crossCheck: true);
        // # Match descriptors.
        DMatch[] bfMatches = bf.Match(featuresA, featuresB);
        //# Sort the features in order of distance.
        //# The points with small distance (more similarity) are ordered first in the vector
        DMatch[] rawMatches = bfMatches.OrderBy(a => a.Distance).ToArray();
        if (rawMatches.Length > 100)
            Array.Resize(ref rawMatches, 100);
        return rawMatches;
    }

    private DMatch[] matchKeyPointsKNN(Mat featuresA, Mat featuresB, double ratio, string method)
    {
        BFMatcher bf = createMatcher(method, crossCheck: false);
        // # compute the raw matches and initialize the list of actual matches
        DMatch[][] rawMatches = bf.KnnMatch(featuresA, featuresB, 2);
        List<DMatch> rawMatches2 = new List<DMatch>();
        //# loop over the raw matches
        DMatch prevmatchN = rawMatches[0][0];
        rawMatches2.Add(prevmatchN);
        for (int m = 0; m < rawMatches.Length; m++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < rawMatches[m].Length; n++)
            {
                //# ensure the distance is within a certain ratio of each
                //# other (i.e. Lowe's ratio test)
                DMatch matchN = rawMatches[m][n];
                if (n == 0)
                    prevmatchN = matchN;
                if (prevmatchN.Distance < matchN.Distance * (ratio))
                    rawMatches2.Add(matchN);
                if (rawMatches2.Count >= 100)
                    break;
            }
        }
        return rawMatches2.ToArray();
    }

    private Mat getHomography(KeyPoint[] kpsA, KeyPoint[] kpsB, Mat featuresA, Mat featuresB, DMatch[] matches, int reprojThresh)
    {
        //# convert the keypoints to numpy arrays
        Point2f[] PtA = new Point2f[matches.Length];
        Point2f[] PtB = new Point2f[matches.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Length; i++)
        {
            KeyPoint kpsAI = kpsA[matches[i].QueryIdx];
            KeyPoint kpsBI = kpsB[matches[i].TrainIdx];

            PtA[i] = new Point2f(kpsAI.Pt.X, kpsAI.Pt.Y);
            PtB[i] = new Point2f(kpsBI.Pt.X, kpsBI.Pt.Y);
        }
        InputArray ptsA = InputArray.Create(PtA);
        InputArray ptsB = InputArray.Create(PtB);
        if (matches.Length > 4)
        {
            //You get the homography matrix usin
            Mat H = Cv2.FindHomography(ptsA, ptsB, HomographyMethods.Ransac, reprojThresh);
            //and then to get any point on the target picture from the original picture:
            //Mat targetPoint = new Mat();
            //Cv2.PerspectiveTransform(ptsA, targetPoint, H);
            return H;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Too Long... did not read. What exactly do you mean by 'I do not get the right output'? We cant guess what your intention is and where the misalignment is between your expectation and the code. Are you running into any exceptions? Or simply the logical outcome is one that you dont expect? If later is the case then I am afraid its logic that would be the problem, not code.

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar I gues I gave my question to fast online... I have edit my question.

Comment: Hmm I think nothing is wrong with the code, it looks like that is very important which image is loaded in as trainImg and which one as queryImg.

Comment: First loaded image is stitched to second one, if I change this, the stitchng do not work... This is not practical... How to fix this? If I understand correct the code the second image is always copyed to location 0,0

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar any suggestions?

Comment: Will try your code today and then comment on it. Lost track of this for a while...

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar did you try it? What about if you dont know which image must be first and which one second, what avout if you want to stitch more than 2 images at the same time?